# Why do the IP and port numbers change when using docker run vs. docker ps?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm attempting to start a docker container from a docker image using the following command:

```
docker run -d \
    --name mycontainer \
    --network my-net \
    -p 192.168.0.19:7777:7777/tcp \
    -p 192.168.0.19:7777:7777/udp \
    -p 192.168.0.19:27015:27015/tcp \
    -p 192.168.0.19:27015:27015/udp \
    cspringer/myimage
```

The container starts fine but when I use `docker ps` to list the running containers I see the following output:

`aa3deb723745        cspringer/mycontainer       "/bin/sh -c '/ark-de…"   2 seconds ago       Up 1 second         127.0.0.1:32769->7777/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32769->7777/udp, 127.0.0.1:32768->27015/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32768->27015/udp   mycontainer`

I'm currently running Docker Desktop on a Windows 10 Home machine using WSL2 and Debian Linux.  192.168.0.19 is the IP address of my host system.

My questions are:

- Why is Docker changing the assigned IP address to the loopback address?
- Why is Docker assigning random port numbers?

To make things even a little stranger, I can actually connect to the service in the running container without a problem.  Additionally, the first time I created the container I did not experience this issue.  I created it last night and stopped the container before the end of the evening.  Then today after starting the container using `docker start mycontainer` it did this.  I then deleted the container and re-created it using the preceding commands.  I have not been able to get it to display properly since that time.

Comment: I do not understand the logic of the edit to my question.  I did not enter the command this way...why edit it?

Comment: I'm not the editor, but the edit is a typical reformatting.  Human readability is much better than your actual command, and all the relevant parameters are preserved.  Improving readability makes it easier for experienced users to answer your quesiton.

Comment: I guess it's a philosophical debate at this point, but I would much rather have the original text of the command vs. convenience.